# Does the __init__ function of a child class need to include all the arguments used in __init__ function of the parent class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have defined a child class B inherited from class A.  I want to give just one parameter in the `__init__` function of B. The `__init__` function of A needs four arguments, which are created in the `__init__` function of A. I was wondering whether this work in Python 3. My code will look like below somehow.

```
class A():
     __init__(self,a1,a2,a3,a4):
          ...
class B(A):
     __init__(self,b):
          ...
          # the arguments a1 a2 a3 a4 for the parent class are generated
          a1 = ...
          a2 = ...
          a3 = ... 
          a4 = ...
          # call the __init__ function of the parent class using super
          super().__init__(a1,a2,a3,a4)

object = B(b0)
```

I copied and modified the code from another person, who used Python 2 instead. When I ran the code in Python 3, I got the following error:
`__init__()` missing 4 required positional arguments: 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', and 'a4'. I was wondering whether this is because I did not include the arguments needed for A in the `__init__()` of B.

**Update**

I just noticed that there was a typo. I wrote `_init_(self, b)` (with single underscore) where I should use `___init__(self, b)` (double underscore). After fixing this typo, the error did not appear. So the answer for my question is "no".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Except for the syntax error, the code you provided doesn't generate the error you mention.

Comment: Also, you most definitely don't want to assign anything to `object`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for your reminder. I did not realize that before.

Answer (score -1):

Shortly, the answer is no. This works in Python3. You don't seem to have any error, except `SyntaxError`. Also, if you have questions, provide your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, a3, a4):
       pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b):
        super().__init__(1,2,3,4)

A(1,2,3,4)
B(1) # no error
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I just noticed that there was a typo. I wrote _init_(self, b) (with single underscore) where I should use ___init__(self, b) (double underscore).